# How do I use set up Twilio in my application to automatically send a text to a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, api, twilio

I have a Ruby on Rails application where users create a "Reminder" and once it is created and saved to the database (POSTGRESQL), the number which the User inputed on making the reminder should be texted a message (by creating a message using Twilio's REST API). My Twilio credentials are correct and my environment variables are set properly in the application.

The reminder is evidently being created (seen after `rails s` in the console) but I am not receiving an SMS at all, and I am wondering if it has to do with the syntax in my `reminder.rb`:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :phone_number, presence: true
  validates :time, presence: true
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :send_text_message

  @@SEND_TEXT_MESSAGE_TIME = 5.minutes

  def send_text_message
    @twilio_phone_number = ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER']
    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    # %k: 24hr time, %M: minute, %p: AM/PM, %b: e.g. "Jan", %d: zero padded day of the month e.g. "01"
    numba = "+1"+self.phone_number
    time_str = ((self.time).localtime).strftime("%k:%M%p on %b. %d")
    body = "Hi. Just a reminder that #{self.title} is coming up at #{time_str}."
    message = @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
      :from => @twilio_phone_number,
      :to => numba,
      :body => body,
      )
    puts message
  end

  def when_to_run
    time - @@SEND_TEXT_MESSAGE_TIME
  end

  handle_asynchronously :send_text_message, :run_at => Proc.new { |i| i.when_to_run }
end
```

The form that the user submits is here:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user,@reminder] do |f| %>
  <% if @reminder.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@reminder.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reminder from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @reminder.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :title , class: "form-control"%>
  <%= f.input :phone_number, class: "form-control", input_html: { value: current_user.phone_number } %>
  <%= f.input :time, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', user_reminders_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

and finally, my `reminders_controller.rb`:

```
class RemindersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.find_by_id params[:user_id]
    @reminders = @user.reminders
    if @reminders.length == 0
      flash[:notice] = 'You have no reminders scheduled. Create one now to get started.'
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id params[:user_id]
    @reminder = @user.reminders.new
  end

  def create
    # Time.zone = reminder_params[:time_zone]
    @user = current_user
    @reminder = @user.reminders.build reminder_params

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reminder.save
        flash[:success] = 'Reminder was created successfully!'
        format.html {
          redirect_to user_reminders_path
        }
      else
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Reminder could not be created. Please try again.'
        format.html {
          render :new 
        }
        format.json {
          render json: @reminder.errors.full_messages
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
   @reminder.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reminder.update_attributes(reminder_params)
        flash[:success] = 'Reminder has been successfully updated.'
        format.html {
          redirect_to user_reminders_path(current_user)
        }
        format.json {
          render json: @reminder
        }
      else
        flash[:error] = 'Reminder could not be updated.'
        format.html {
          redirect_to edit_reminder_path
        }
        format.json {
          render json: @reminder.errors.full_messages
        }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @reminder = Reminder.find(params[:id])
    @reminder.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_reminders_path(current_user.id), notice: 'reminder was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def reminder_params
    params.require(:reminder).permit(:title, :time, :phone_number)
  end
end
```

Am I missing something? I am new to rails and am more used to the MEAN stack, so I am thinking it is maybe my use of variables and the self keyword that are messing things up for me. I am looking for advice on anything I can do or fix to make the Message resource from Twilio's REST API send a text to a number that I input.

Comment: Quick question, are you using live or test Twilio credentials?  I ask b/c text messages won't be sent if you're using test creds.  Assuming you're using live credentials and Twilio isn't the issue, I would recommend commenting out your handle_asynchronously line as delayed_job will make this harder to debug.  Pry (it's a Ruby gem) is an excellent way to work through issues like this.  After adding it to your Gemfile, you can stick a binding.pry right after your Twilio create call.  This will help you verify that you're getting into that method and let you inspect the message variable.

Comment: The credentials are not the problem. I am now receiving messages per suggestion by @philnash on the deprecated code, but I had to not use delayed job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

@ajporterfield makes a couple of good suggestions, make sure you're using live, not test, credentials and try making this work without delaying the method.

I have a couple of other questions. Are you [running the delayed job process](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs) to process the jobs?

Have you [upgraded your account](https://www.twilio.com/user/billing)? If you are still using a free Twilio account you will need to make sure that all the numbers you send messages to are verified in your account. Once you upgrade your account you can send messages to any number.

Finally, one suggestion: you are currently calling `@twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create`. The `sms.messages` endpoint in the API is actually deprecated right now so it is better to just call `messages`. Also, as a convenience, if you are using the main account, you don't need to call `account` either. So you can actually shorten that line to: `@twilio_client.messages.create` and it will work better and look tidier.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: By shortening my line to `@twilio_client.messages.create`, I am finally receiving text messages. However, I had to comment out the `when_to_run` and `handle_asynchronously` methods. I noticed that successful POSTs made the browser hang half a second more after I created that reminder.

Comment: Ok, so were you running the delayed_job task runner when you were testing this before?

Comment: Yes, I was. But with the shortened POST request and with delayed_job running, I am not receiving messages.

Comment: The POST request is shorter because you are just saving the job rather than calling the Twilio API. So the issue you are having seems to be with how delayed job is working. Can you return the `handle_asynchronously` command, but leave out the `:run_at` option and see what happens?

Comment: Only comment out `:run_at` and beyond?

Comment: So nothing happened, I will look at the delayed_job docs and see if I am missing anything.